# Can't remove bottom navigation screen

Tags: python, kivymd

Like when you run the open_contacts function, so that the bottom navigation bar is removed. And there was a blank screen Here is the code
everything works, but when running the function I would like the bottom bar to disappear

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.navigationbar import (
    MDNavigationBar,
    MDNavigationItem,
    MDNavigationItemLabel,
    MDNavigationItemIcon,
)
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.recycleview import MDRecycleView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from datetime import datetime
import ast
import configparser  # импортируем библиотеку


class BaseMDNavigationItem(MDNavigationItem):
    icon = StringProperty()
    text = StringProperty()
    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_widget(MDNavigationItemIcon(icon=self.icon))
        self.add_widget(MDNavigationItemLabel(text=self.text))



class BaseScreen_group(MDScreen):
    image_size = StringProperty()
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()  # создаём объекта парсера
        config.read("group.ini", encoding="utf-8")  # читаем конфиг
        def main_menu():
            self.layout = MDGridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
            self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
            self.layout.clear_widgets() 
            back_button = Button(text='< Добавить группу',on_press=lambda x: add_group(''),
                                size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))
            self.layout.add_widget(back_button)
            root = MDRecycleView(size=(Window.width, Window.height))                    
            root.add_widget(self.layout)
            self.add_widget(root)
        def perebor_group():
            main_menu()
            for value in config:  # Добавляет меню
                if value != 'DEFAULT':
                    btn = Button(text=str(value), on_press=lambda x, value=value: open_group(contact=f'{value}') , size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))  # Добавляет кнопки групп
                    self.layout.add_widget(btn) 
        def open_group(contact):
            """Открыть группу в которой все контакты этой группы"""
            self.layout.clear_widgets() 
            new_layout = MDGridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
            new_layout.bind(minimum_height=new_layout.setter('height'))
            new_back_button = Button(text='< Назад', on_press=lambda x: perebor_group(),
                                    size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))
            new_layout.add_widget(new_back_button)
            for value in config[f'{contact}']:
                contact = Button(text=f'{value}', on_press=lambda x: '', size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))    
                new_layout.add_widget(contact)
            root = MDRecycleView()
            root.add_widget(new_layout)
            self.add_widget(root)
            # self.layout = new_layout


        def edit_group(text_button, value):
            """Сохранение изменений в файле"""
            config.set('user_group', f'{text_button}', f'{value}')
            with open('group.ini', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as configfile:
                config.write(configfile)


        def add_group(group):  #Доделать
            """Добавить группу контактов"""
            config = configparser.ConfigParser()  # создаём объекта парсера
            config.read("group.ini", encoding="utf-8")  # читаем конфиг
            with open('group.ini', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.write(group)
            # Как то нужно вызвать кнопку текста, чтобы добавить группу
            # Сделать фильтр если такая кнопка то просто отображения списка контактов или групп
        def main():
            """Логика программы"""
            perebor_group()
        main()

class BaseScreen_contact(MDScreen):
    image_size = StringProperty()
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()  # создаём объекта парсера
        config.read("group.ini", encoding="utf-8")  # читаем конфиг
        def main_menu():
            self.layout = MDGridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
            self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
            self.layout.clear_widgets() 
            add_contact = Button(text='< Добавить контакт',on_press=lambda x: add_contacts(),
                                size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))
            self.layout.add_widget(add_contact)
            root = MDRecycleView(size=(Window.width, Window.height))                    
            root.add_widget(self.layout)
            self.add_widget(root)
        def perebor_contacts():
            main_menu()
            for group in config:  # Добавляет меню
                if group != 'DEFAULT':
                    for value in config[f'{group}']:
                        btn = Button(text=str(value), on_press=lambda x, value=value, group=group: open_contacts(contact=f'{value}', group=group) , size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))  # Добавляет кнопки групп
                        
                        self.layout.add_widget(btn) 
        def open_contacts(contact, group):
            """Открывает все доступные контракты"""
            
            self.layout.clear_widgets() 

            

        def add_contacts():  #Доделать
            """Добавить группу контактов"""
            config = configparser.ConfigParser()  # создаём объекта парсера
            config.read("group.ini", encoding="utf-8")  # читаем конфиг
            # with open('group.ini', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            #     file.write(group)
            # Как то нужно вызвать кнопку текста, чтобы добавить группу
            
        def main():
            """Логика программы"""
            perebor_contacts()
        main()


class Example(MDApp):
    show_navigation_bar = True
    def on_switch_tabs(
        self,
        bar:  MDNavigationBar,
        item: MDNavigationItem,
        item_icon: str,
        item_text: str,
    ):
        self.root.get_ids().screen_manager.current = item_text
        self.show_navigation_bar = False  # Hide the navigation bar


    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        
        if self.show_navigation_bar:
            self.show_navigation_bar = MDBoxLayout(
        MDScreenManager(
            BaseScreen_group(
                name="Группы",
                image_size="1024",
            ),
            BaseScreen_contact(
                name="Контакты",
                image_size="1024",
            ),
            id="screen_manager",
        ),
        MDNavigationBar(
            BaseMDNavigationItem(
                # icon="gmail",
                text="Группы",
                active=True,
            ),
            BaseMDNavigationItem(
                # icon="sex",
                text="Контакты",
            ),
            on_switch_tabs=self.on_switch_tabs,
            

        ),
        orientation="vertical",
        md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.backgroundColor,)
        else:
            self.show_navigation_bar = MDBoxLayout(
        MDScreenManager(
            BaseScreen_group(
            ),
            BaseScreen_contact(
            ),
            id="screen_manager",
        ),)
        return self.show_navigation_bar
            


Example().run()
```

everything works, but when running the function I would like the bottom bar to disappear